# How to create a system app for custom ROM

Tags: android, android-source

We have a custom ROM for a device we are making and what I want to do is make our own custom Settings app to replace the settings app that comes already built in android.

I cant really find any documentation on how to even create a system app. It does not appear you can create it in Android Studio, I tried looking on the AOSP site and didnt find anything there related to creating system apps. The few things I did find were on here where you would put `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in your manifest and then has to be signed with the same key as the ROM but after that I cant find anything.

The settings app I want to create would need access to the `framework.jar` to be able to use the hidden framework API's.

Does anyone have any information or know where I can find this information on how to go about actually creating a system app?

Comment: I don't have all the info you need, but the system app is just like any other app. The only difference is it's going to be signed with an OS certificate so you can use shared user id. Apart from that, you need to place your apk at particular destination i.e /system/app or /system/priv-app. One way to do is to change the make script of AOSP build, so during compilation, the ROM will automatically copy the apk to that path and sign it. I did this around 4 years back and that's the only info I can recall right now

Comment: First of all. What do you use: mk, bp or graddle files? When  you try to to build system application you must sign it by system certificate. After that you will have system app and can use android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

Comment: @AndreySamoilov Gradle files

Comment: @tyczj So, in the case you must have platform certificate and create according task. Something like that:

```
    signingConfigs {
        aerndappsigning {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file('debug_platform_key/platform.jks')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

Comment: @AndreySamoilov OP probably has an AOSP project since he is build rom, in this case, settings in android.mk could sign the apk, no need to sign it in gradle/android studio

Answer (score 0):

You may want to research how to make a Device Tree Overlay (dto). Basically it is your code, reformatting the base code, into what you want. https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/dto?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you use Gradle, you should put first build you apk and put them in you vender folder, and next important thing is to create a mk/bp file to tell the Android build system how to deal with this pre-built apk.

P.S. If you system app highly depends on Android hidden api, make sure you have the right version of framework.jar in you Android Studio project, or, as what I alway did, create apps directly in AOSP, in this case, you can just check the code structure of the original Settings app in AOSP

[this](http://burningthumb.com/android-mk-file-add-apk-systempriv-app/) tutorial may help you.